# Schema Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony

Tengo la siguiente duda:

Si modifico la DB de forma manual, por ejemplo cambio el nombre de una tabla o columna, debo modificar el esquema de symfony para que siga funcionando ?

Ya que necesito hacer este trabajo en una web de producción y tengo esa duda ya que no encuentro información por ninguna parte.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta: Si

Respuesta larga:

Hace años que no veo un symfony 1.4 pero recuerdo que existe un archivo schema.yml que describe los objetos de PHP y como se "mapean" con las tablas de la base de datos, esto es lo que se conoce como ORM (Object Relational Mapping), este schema siempre tiene que estar actualizado, de otra forma el ORM intentará hidratar, persistir, modificar o eliminar los objetos usando columnas que no existen.